# Expected number of rounds in a game based on chance

Tags: probability, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, expected-value

Suppose we have a game where we roll one die first. If the number is a one, then we reroll two dice in its place. We continue this until there are no more ones, and the score is all the numbers added together that weren't 1s. Ex. John rolls a dice, gets a 1, then he rerolls two more dice in its place. He gets a 3 and a 1. The 3 remains, but the 1 is replaced by two dice, which are a 5 and a 6. Then his score is 3+5+6 = 14.

If he gets any number besides a 1 on the first roll, game ends.

How would I find the expected number of rounds that will occur. (new round happens when a 1 occurs).

Comment: If he rolls double $1$'s one the second roll, does he roll four dice on the third roll?

Comment: Yes, always replaces a one with two other dice rolls

Comment: This appears to be related to a question from the [MathCamp](http://www.mathcamp.org/) application or similar, and has been asked without providing that key context, just like this user's other question (which was literally copied from a mathcamp document). See problem 2 at http://www.mathcamp.org/2019/qquiz_applicantID_INSERTYOURAPPLICANTIDHERE.tex

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's from a contest